# How to schedule/run python script remotely using jenkins

Tags: python, github, jenkins, continuous-integration, pytest

I have a Python test script in a GitHub repo that I am looking to run every few hours. Now, I know I can use Jenkins to schedule the executions and have them run locally on my machine, but my question is how do I do this without the need for my machine to be powered on? In other words, is there a way to run a script not locally and through some headless service? My company does use circleCI, is that what I would use?

Answer (score 1):

A "cron" schedule in Jenkins would let you run tests on a repeating schedule. Details from this Stack Overflow question: [Configure cron job to run every 15 minutes on Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19443732/configure-cron-job-to-run-every-15-minutes-on-jenkins)

You also mentioned CircleCI, and for that you'll find some useful information about configuring the `.yml` file here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22028637/7058266

Since you're using GitHub, you'll also be able to do that using GitHub Actions: [How can I get Selenium tests to run in python with Github actions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62364711/how-can-i-get-selenium-tests-to-run-in-python-with-github-actions)

You'll need to set a cron timing in that `.yml` file (details in https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions):

```yaml
on:
  schedule:
    # * is a special character in YAML so you have to quote this string
    - cron:  '30 5,17 * * *'
```

If you need more assistance, I created a video a few years ago about how to set up Jenkins for Python/pytest Selenium testing on Jenkins from Google Cloud using [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n-sno20R9P0

(If you're just running a Python/pytest script without Selenium, just ignore the Selenium-specific parts.)

Comment: Thanks. If I go these routes, where will the script be executed? Because I don’t want it to run locally as I don’t want to have to have my machine powered on.

Comment: The script would be executed from the server that hosts the CI/CD platform that you have chosen, whether that be Jenkins, CircleCI, GitHub Actions, or other.